# How to get the ip of the client that is connected to the modbus server?

Tags: modbus, pymodbus, pymodbustcp

I am using `ModbusTcpServer(context, identity=identity, address=(listener_address, listener_port))`, here ModbusTcpServer is a function that is imported from pymodbus, I want to get the IP of client that get connected to the server for the logging purpose but unable to find a solution. It will be very helpful if someone can give a solution

Comment: If you enable debug logs, you should see it as part of the logs. Refer https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/blob/master/pymodbus/server/sync.py#L46

Comment: Actually I am trying to use a implemented version on internet [link](https://bitbucket.org/Cybcon/modbus-server/src/master/) and it has mention logging format (in defualt configuration )which does not include client IP, hoping someone know the keyword to include to get that ip.

Answer (score 0):

`for connection_id in self.server.active_connections:`
      `connection=self.server.active_connections[connection_id]`
      `peername=connection.transport.get_extra_info("peername")`

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**